# MySQL: User some_user_name already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I'm using Zend Freamwork for my website. And sometimes i get the following exception from my website:

> Message: SQLSTATE[42000] [1203] User elibrary_books already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections

As I know "Zend Freamwork" uses PDO to connect to the database.
How i can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Always close your connection. If you are using Sql class it looks like:

```
$sql->getAdapter()->getDriver()->getConnection()->disconnect();
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes MySQL connection thread is not thrown away even though you've torn down the socket cleanly; it still hangs around waiting for it to be reaped.

Check your settings for `wait_timeout`. Default value is unreasonably long. Optimal value might be around 20 seconds. You will probably also want it this low if you're using persistent connections.

Comment: How can i set "wait_timeout" for PDO?

Comment: You can set wait_timeout as a session variable each time you open a connection by issuing the query:

SET wait_timeout=28800;

If you're using PDO (a much better choice than the MySQL or MySQLi drivers), you can issue the above statement by setting a PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND driver option when creating the PDO connection object.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the persistent flag in your database driver configuration to be false:

```
resources.db.params.persistent = 0
```

Comment: this did not help i'm getting the same message.